# How do I create another unique view for each device?

Tags: view, swiftui, navigationview

How do I create another view when the user chooses a device ? For each device, the view will not be the same because the information given will not be the same ( custom view )
Thank you to put me on the track.

[Canvas image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faVRY.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    List(Ios, children: \.sousMenuIos) { item in
        HStack {
            Image(item.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                .bold()
        }
  }
    .navigationTitle("Jailbreak")
   }
  }
 }
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
```

Comment: Does this help? [SwiftUI Navigation View - Handling Size Classes over multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077920/swiftui-navigation-view-handling-size-classes-over-multiple-views).

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, and it's also not a minimal example with working runnable code.

Comment: However, I find that quite clear. I just want to open a specific view for each device in my list

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot Oh, you mean navigate to a new view (which may contain more information about the device)? If so, you are probably looking for `NavigationLink`. _Btw: use `@...` when replying so I get a notification_

Comment: Just select the file target in the project navigator. You can call the specific file/view the same thing and Xcode will pick the correct one based on which file is available for the target

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your list label in a NavigationLink and pass the item to the costum view that you want. here is a working example with dummy data.

```
struct ListItems: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(iOS.previewData) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: CostumView(text: item.name)){
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: item.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                        .bold()
                }
            }
  }
    .navigationTitle("Jailbreak")
   }
  }
 }
struct CostumView: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View{
        Text(text)
    }
}

struct ListItems_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListItems()
    }
}

struct iOS: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image: String = ""
    var name: String
    
    static let previewData = [
    iOS(image: "phone", name: "iPhone 8"),
    iOS(image: "phone", name: "iPhone X")
    ]
}
```